# Blazor Server Side - SAML2 Authentication

Tags: saml-2.0, blazor-server-side

Good Day Everyone

Our Global Company is using SAML2 for our Single Sign-On Authentication (We don't use any other external authentication like Facebook, Google and Twitter), we are successfully created a SAML2 on our ASP.NET Webforms and MVC, but haven't done it on ASP.NET Core (MVC and Blazor), I search on the internet and found this:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp

I haven't applied it on my ASP.NET Core MVC project, but my team want's me to use SAML2 to my Blazor Server Application project, but when I tried to create a cookie authentication on Blazor, It seems that the authentication approach of the Core MVC and Blazor Server Side is different to each other, and I think on the link above will might not work to my Blazor App, what do you think? Does someone here has successfully created Blazor Side Application that has a SAML2 Authentication?

I hope someone can help me on this and guide me.

Thanks and regards

Comment: "Ask and you shall get. @dotnet Blazor Server using Azure AD and SAML to authenticate users using Single Sign On (SSO) - Blog post to follow" https://github.com/425show/BlazorServerAuthWithSAML #blazor #aspnet #dotnet #security #microsoftIdentity https://twitter.com/ChristosMatskas/status/1433222794079207431 " / Twitter

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late response and thanks for your suggestions, but I solved this by creating an ASP.NET Core MVC and then add the Blazor Components on it, and then using the [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2), I was in a tight schedule so I chose this approach, and we are not currently using Azure, I will try your solutions if I have new project

Thanks everyone.